# Adding components programmatically has different style than those in XML layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-styles

Components (text and edit boxes) defined in layout XML looks very different from those i add programatically.

I've tried to apply the same textAppearance style programatically as the ones from my XML has. I tried calling `setTheme()` after adding the components too. No difference.

```java
    TextView tv10 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv10.setText("Back width");
    EditText tv11 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    tv11.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

`TextView` comes out with small font and gray text, `EditText` comes out with black background and gray text. 
The components must be added programmatically because of options the user choose. Those user choices are defined in the XML and follow the expected color scheme, which is the Android Studio defaults. (Black text on white background)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Application Context for views. Only Activity context. Also you can pass style as parameter, when create view in code.

Comment: Using parentView.getContext() instead of getApplicationContext() made it work as expected.

Comment: @CupOfQuestions good to hear. Could you mark my answer as the right one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Yamko said, style can be passed in the constuctor

```
var textView = TextView(context, null, R.style.LoginBodyTextViewStyle)
```

where the style can be something like

```xml
<style name="LoginBodyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_default</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```